# URL parsing library with IDN support

Tags: c++, c

Is there any good plain C (or at least C++) library for parsing URL's that also supports [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name), so that it can easily parse url like [http://президент.рф/](http://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/)

Answer (score 2):

There's [Google URL](http://code.google.com/p/google-url/), which is a C++ library for parsing and canonicalizing URLs. It supports UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoded URLs using the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/).